# Make an ajax request with elements attributes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an ajax request where I want to give all my elements attributes. For exemple i select all my elements :

```
var elements = $('.droppable')
```

and then i make my ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     data: {myelements : elements},
      success: function(){

      }
  });
```

How can i do to give all my elements attributes as **height, width, position, top, left**... to my ajax request. I have to make an array myself or there is an other way?

I want to do that because i want to save in database all the absolute position of my elements.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this yourself, make a list of attributes you want. So you don't have to do `{ width : "width", height : "height" }` etc. With the following method you can put an array with css elements and attr elements, to a array which will be used as a loop.

You might even want to separate the `attr` and `css` arrays, because when you get it back from the server you can loop through each elements attributes and css objects.

Like:

```
var attr = ["name", "id"];
var css = ["position", "left", "top"];
var elementsData = [];

$('.droppable').each(function(){
    var data = {};
    for(var i in attr)
    {
        data[ attr[i] ] = $(this).attr( attr[i] );
    }
    for(var i in css)
    {
        data[ css[i] ] = $(this).css( css[i] );
    }

    elementsData.push(data);
});


$.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     data: {myelements : elementsData},
      success: function(){
          $('.droppable').addClass("done");
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use $(this) inside the success for ajax, in this case use elements.addClass('done');

also the only way you'll be able to give multiple elements different height/width/pos is you would have to post a unique id of each element to the ajax form and then the responce would have to be an object containing the unique id, height, width, pos of that element (most likely json) so you can select each element by it's unique id and then change the values based on the object returned

Comment: You *can* use `$(this)`, if you set the `context` property of the settings object. It isn't worth it here, though, I agree.

Comment: @lonesomeday I've never known about `context` :x can you use `context:$(this)` and then use $(this) in the success?

Comment: Well, the jQuery object would be `this`, so you wouldn't need to wrap it in the jQuery constructor, but, otherwise, yes. So you could do `this.append(result)`, for example, to add the result to the end of the element in the jQuery selection.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to loop through the elements and post each one to the database separately.  have your server method return a json object that you can use to find the elment on the page to update the class

```
$(".droppable").each(function(index, item){
  var id = $(item).attr("id"); //server will pass this back so you can select it later
  var height = $(item).css("height");
  var width = $(item).css("width");
   // etc.
  $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     data: {id: height: height, width: width}, //add each property
      success: function(data){ //data is returned by your server method
          $(data.elementId).addClass("done"); //you passed elementId to the server as 'id'
      }
  });
});
```

if you want to do it in one request, you could set up an associative array and pass that.  it's late here, and this is off the top of my head.  this may not be the exact syntax, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction

```
var elements = new Array();
$(".droppable").each(function(index, item){
  var id = $(item).attr("id"); //server will pass this back so you can select it later
  var height = $(item).css("height");
  var width = $(item).css("width");
   // etc.

  var item = { id: id, height: height, width: width };
  elements.push(item); //an array of objects
});

  $.ajax({
     url: "test.html",
     data: {elements: elements}
      success: function(data){ //data is returned by your server method
         // set the class on success 
      }
  });
```

Comment: Mmmm it's many request, i will have maybe 300/400 objects :) But you right, that's one solution, but i don't think the best in my case. Thank you